# type(number) == (float or int) returns false python

Tags: python

I'm checking if the argument of a function is a float or an int with this line and it keeps return false, can anyone explain why this happens?

```
def distance_from_zero(number):
    if type(number) == (int or float):
        return abs(number)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

Comment: You must write it as `if type(number) == int or type(number) == float`. Shorter forms are also possible.

Comment: @XiaoyuLu No, not really

Comment: @XiaoyuLu If the value is an `int`, it evaluates to `True`. Otherwise, it evaluates to `float`, which is truthy. As a result, the function will *always* return `abs(number)`, regardless of its type.

Comment: Type sniffing aside, returning a string from a function that ostensibly returns a distance is a bad idea. Raise an exception instead.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the explanation. I was confused in the first place. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

***This is the shortest, most pythonic way.***

Use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(number, (int, float)):
```

Comment: Most pythonic is not doing type-checking at all.  For example, the answer from [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233554/674039) also works, without any extra code necessary, for complex numbers and fractions.

Comment: @wim - The op is checking for int or float. What kind of scenario would merit not using `isinstance`?

Comment: I'm saying what the OP is doing is not Pythonic in the first place. Duck-typing is better.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp) you could use an exception instead of explicit type checking, like

```
def distance_from_zero(number):
    try:
        return abs(number)
    except TypeError:
        return 'Nope'


for x in [1, 1.1, 'a']:
    print(x, distance_from_zero(x))

1 1
1.1 1.1
a Nope
```

IMO this is often clearer and more foolproof.

Comment: Returning a string when the caller is likely expecting a number if anything but foolproof.

Comment: @chepner  True, but not really fair to neg them on that because it was from the question.  And without it, this may as well be `distance_from_zero = abs`  :)

Comment: @wim @chepner I agree and wouldn't return `'Nope'` if this were my code :)

Comment: It *should* just be `distance_from_zero = abs` :)